# Smart pointers - unique_ptr for a stack-allocated variable

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have the following simple code, and I have not found a thread where smart pointers are used for this simple case, but rather copy objects:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 1;

    std::unique_ptr<int> p1(&i);
    *p1 = 2;

    return 0;
}
```

This results in `_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_INVALID` when the pointer goes out of scope. If I call `p1.release()`, the code works fine and I do not get this error. I thought such pointers are smart enough to handle dangling pointers?

An alternative would be if I had a copy of i, which does not give the above error:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> p1(new int(i));
```

What is the advantage of using smart pointers here, where I do not want to perform the local copy?

If I were to use a raw pointer:

```
int i = 1;
int *p1 = &i;
*p1 = 2;
```

I would not get an error, even if I don't code:

```
p1 = nullptr;
```

Answer (score 15):

`std::unique_ptr`s are for handling dynamically allocated memory; they're said to *take ownership* of the pointer when you construct one.

Your `int i;` is on the stack, and thus isn't dynamically allocated; it's ownership can't be taken away from the stack. When the `unique_ptr` destructor tries to `delete` the pointer you gave it (because it thinks nobody owns it anymore), you get that error because `delete` can only be used for pointers created with `new`.

Given your short example, I don't know what context this is in... But you should use raw pointers (or make a copy, as you said) for stack-allocated variables.

Comment: Thank you both, this makes sense. Also, why can't I just do p1 = nullptr rather than p1.release(). I understand that release() returns a pointer to the managed object and releases the ownership. p1.reset() replaces the managed object, so it makes sense that's illegal for the stack allocated variable. But why does p1 = nullptr compile, but raise an exception?

Comment: Assigning a `unique_ptr` with [`=`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/operator=/) is basically the same as calling [`reset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/reset/), and destroys the previously-held pointer. Using [`release`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/release/) gives up ownership of the pointer, without destroying it.

Comment: `p1=nullptr` is a assignment, p1 should clean up its pointer then hold the nullptr. This is what a owner need to do. `p1.release()` is to give away its "ownership" and return its holding pointer to others, and not manage anymore so it does not clean it.

Answer (score 4):

The answer provided by @qzx is the main reason of the problem you've reported in your code

One additional thing about `std::unique_ptr<>` usage. You should always try to use `std::make_unique<>()` to create a `std::unique_ptr`. It sometimes help in using this pointer appropriately by providing appropriate compilation errors.

For example, if you change the above code with `std::make_unique<>` as

```
int i = 1;
std::unique_ptr<int> p1 = make_unique<int>(&i);
```

then most compiler will give error as

```
can't convert int* to int
```

It will help you to use a copy which creates a totally new integer whose ownership is taken by `std::unique_ptr<>`

```
int i = 1;
std::unique_ptr<int> p1 = make_unique<int>(i);
*p1 = 2;
```

This code works.

Comment: So there's no advantage to using the smart pointer in this case, as opposed to a reference to i, int &p = i, since &p is dereferenced when it goes out of scope. I guess it's better to use the smart pointer in a class declaration for example. make_unique is available in c++14 onwards? My VS2012 compiler doesn't recognise it.