c++ passing ownership to composite class
I have an object (let's call it A) that I want to store another object (let's say it has type B and is called m), which will be passed from the function that creates A. The creation of B is made by another function that I don't have control over.
class A
{
    public:
    A(B& m)
    {
        this->m = m
    }

    private:
    B& m;
};

//

void SomeLongLivedClass::someFunction()
{
    B m = createB();
    A a = new A{ m }

    // m goes out of scope
}

When someFunction()'s scope ends, m is destroyed and the reference in A becomes dangling. I can only obtain the right B through createB(), which is a part of a dll I don't have access to. How can I make m an lvalue and pass ownership to A?
I chose to create B outside of A to reduce clutter in A, but maybe that's a fundamentally wrong way to do it? I've read a little about composition vs. aggregation - is it wrong to do composition by shoving objects into a class like this?
I thought about passing m as an std::unique_ptr<B>, but I can't wrap my head around whether or not m will still go out of scope, and then leave the pointer dangling instead.
It goes without saying that this is just pseudocode and the real situation is more complicated. The creation of B is a little more involved than that, which is why I wanted to do it outside A.

A a = new A won't compile.  The result of the new A expression is a A* pointer.

You should store a B in A, not a B&. If you store a reference, then accessing the referenced object after it's gone out of scope has undefined behavior.
Instead, copy or move m into A. A simple version is to take B by value in A's constructor:
class A {
public:
    A(B m) : m(std::move(m)) {}    // take by value, then move

private:
    B m;
};

Another alternative is to provide one or both of these constructors:
class A {
public:
    A(const B& m) : m(m) {}        // copy m
    A(B&& m) : m(std::move(m)) {}  // move m
    
private:
    B m;
};

Then in the calling code, if you have an lvalue, cast it to an rvalue reference by using std::move:
void SomeLongLivedClass::someFunction() {
    B m = createB();
    // 
    auto a = std::make_unique<A>(std::move(m));
    //
}

Note: This assumes that B is well-written with respect to ownership of resources, which all classes in the standard library are and presumably/hopefully the DLL writers did a good job too.

This function does not appear to be clear and complete. Looks like this has other issues also.
void SomeLongLivedClass::someFunction()
{
    B m = createB();
    A a = new A{ m }

    // m goes out of scope
}

When you say m goes out of scope, did you call delete before (delete m)? Otherwise it is a memory leak. If you have already called it then anyway m is not accessible.
Both m & a are local variables of function someFunction. so unless you have some code in someFunction which stores value of object a (may be in any member variable of SomeLongLivedClass) object a also goes out of scope. Hence no point in worrying about child object B of class A, since object of class A itself goes out of scope.
That is the reason I believe code is incomplete.
However when you decide to store object of A in someFunction in member variable of SomeLongLivedClass, like below:
void SomeLongLivedClass::someFunction()
{
    B m = createB();
    A a = new A{ m }
    m_A = a; // m_A is member variable of SomeLongLivedClass with type A*
    m_B = m; // m_B is member variable of SomeLongLivedClass with type B*
    // m goes out of scope
}

Then you can also store object of B in some other member variable of SomeLongLivedClass right?
Then both object of A & object of B are long lived.
In that scenario you do not have any issues either.

You seem to be giving Java advice to a C++ question.  Java variables are all pointers to heap memory, but C++ variables are only pointers if they carry the * modifier.  B m neither needs to be, nor can it be, the expression passed to delete m.

@Ben Voigt
, I am also a C++ developer not a Java developer. Hence I know the pointers and other stuffs. I have just copied the original code to suggest how to store it. Whatever the typo original question had was reproduced in my answer.
I believe the the one who asked this question at least aware of those pointer things. So it could be a typo in the question

Well, your answer started by talking about delete on something that's not a pointer.  The question did have multiple errors, but that one didn't come from the question.

@Ben Voigt , how did you conclude that it is not a pointer ? If you noticed the question , he is mentioning std::unique_ptr . It means B is a pointer right. The question has typo. It says A a = new A{ m } here A is pointer right ? Similarly B is also looks to be a pointer since he mentioned std::unique_ptr.

std::unique_ptr<B> doesn't mean B is a pointer, it makes a pointer to a B.  A a = new A{} is just wrong, it needs to be A* a = new A.  Even if A is already a pointer, you still cannot write A a = new A because new A would then be a double pointer.

std::unique_ptr is for dynamically allocated variables.  It cannot be used for stack allocated variables. Hence if one has to use std::unique_ptr then B is allocated dynamically. He mentions passing ownership. Such things are only meant for pointer types.

@Ben Voigt , just for the reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41254412/smart-pointers-unique-ptr-for-a-stack-allocated-variable

@Ben Voigt, when some one talks about passing owneship, it is for dynamic objects right? What ownership we expect from a stack objects  ? Stack object cleaning is either the responsibility of callee or caller based on calling convention. So there is no responsibility from the user (who writes C++ code). Only for dynamically allocated objects such need do arise.

Given that there is a DLL involved, in order to support different compilers and runtime libraries, it's very likely that the returned value is actually some sort of handle, not a stack object.  And that this handle can be easily copied around (as Ted is instructing OP to do).  So you're thinking in the right direction about dynamic allocation helping with the lifetime problem, but you can't use C++ delete on all dynamically allocated objects, and specifically you can't on a handle that came from a DLL. The only way to free the object that came from createB is going to be the DLL's freeB

Hi @Ben Voigt , you are right.  I have overlooked the DLL he is mentioning. If it is windows it will be a HANDLE type. Since they are implemented in C they are most likely to be malloc or such kinds. Hence free may be the right one.

Don't answer too fast. You are not answering the question and your answer is wrong. In C and C++, you need & to get a pointer, the assignment is for reference, also neither extend the lifetime of an variable. Also the OP did not mentioned manual dynamic allocation so why you mention delete ? And why a pointer instead of the much safer C++ reference ?

@DevilishSpirits: References are NOT SAFER than pointers.

@BenVoigt Java variables are not pointers to heap memory if they are primitive types, such as int rather than object types.

It is mentioned std::unique_ptr means it is for dynamic allocation only right ? Still do not understand  what is the confusion here. But that dynamic allocation need not be new as @Ben Voigt mentioned. Which I will agree. Dynamic allocation could have come from malloc, VirtualAlloc which ever which ultimately uses heap memory.

Hi @Ben Voigt, when I mentioned delete , my intention was did the memory freed  ? If not it is a memory leak. If it is then anyway B is not accessible. Hence unless those variable lifetime is extended by storing them (may be through member variable) they are anyway out of scope . Both A & B. Hence my stand is question is not complete. There are many unknowns.
